# Construct object from few JSON properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my JSON data I have a lot of fields and some of them I'd like to merge in one object.
Can I implement that with `JsonDeserializer`?

JSON example:
`{
   field1 : "value1",
   field2 : "value2",
   field3 : "value3"
}`

That I need as a result:

```
class ClassA {
    ClassB field1And2;
    String field3;
}

class ClassB {
    String field1;
    String field2;
}
```

Comment: You can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: We already use Jackson for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can. see below.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=ChildDeserializer.class)
class Child{
private Name name;
private int age=13;

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public Name getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(Name name) {
    this.name = name;
}


}

class Name {
private String chFName;
private String chLName;

public Name(String f, String l) {
    chFName=f;
    chLName=l;
}

public String getChFName() {
    return chFName;
}
public void setChFName(String chFName) {
    this.chFName = chFName;
}
public String getChLName() {
    return chLName;
}
public void setChLName(String chLName) {
    this.chLName = chLName;
}
}

class ChildDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Child> {
@Override
public Child deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
     ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        String fName=  node.get("fName").textValue();
        String lName=  node.get("lName").textValue();
        int age=  node.get("age").intValue();
        Child ch = new Child();
        ch.setName(new Name(fName, lName));
        ch.setAge(age);
        return ch;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException,     IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.readValue("{\"fName\":\"first\",\"lName\":\"last\",\"age\":13}", Child.class);
}
```

Comment: But I have other fields to store in parent class. I've added example to question.

Comment: I guess my example is similar.. ClassA is the "Child" and "Name" is ClassB.

Comment: Yes, but I will have to write deserializers for all cllasses that contains ClassB (I have lots of them) and manually write all other fields.